# AngularFire2: ERROR Error: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, firebase-security

Not sure why I'm getting this error while accessing AngularFirestoreCollection:

> ERROR Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.

```
this.categories = afs.collection('categories').doc(this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid).collection<Category>('categories');
```

Firestore Database Rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /categories/{userId}{
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: From your code it looks like you're trying to access `/categories/{userId}/categories`, yet your rule is only for `/categories/{userId}`. Try changing it to `match /categories/{category=**} {`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured a deep path in your application:

```
Categories --> User --> Categories
```

And your rules only contains the parent folder which is:

```
/categories/{userId}
```

You have to change to:

```
/categories/{userId}/categories/{category}
```

So you have access to UserId for the matching condition, plus to the effect of the current path.

There are many reasons when to use wildcards and when to use specific or nested matching conditions, Take a look at the [main docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure) and choose your best fit implementation.

Comment: I tried using wildcard ( /categories/{userId=**} ) but got the same error. But using full path as suggested worked. Am I using wildcard correctly ?

Comment: Also is the structure I'm using to store user categories correct or is their a more efficient way ?

Comment: Im not sure whats the goal of your application, but if you need to manage an extra collection of categories for each user, it seems okay.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.

Check before you making the call if you actually already signed in :

```
isSignedIn() {
  this.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    console.log("User is signed in.");

    } else {
      console.log("No user is signed in.");
    }
});
```